# Pandas to stata does not preserve boole type

Tags: python, pandas

When I export a pandas dataframe to Stata's `.dta` format, any boolean variable will be lost after loading this data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(100)})
df['positive'] = df['a'] > 0
df.to_stata('~/test.dta')
print(df['positive'].head())
test = pd.read_stata('~/test.dta', convert_categoricals=False)
print(test['positive'].head())
```

The output of this is:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: positive, dtype: bool
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: positive, dtype: int8
```

Is there a way to preserve the boolean type of the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use the convert_strl parameter in to_stata function. 
use of this is to give the list of column names to convert to string columns to Stata StrL format. Only available if the version is 117. Storing strings in the StrL format can produce smaller dta files if strings have more than 8 characters and values are repeated.
in version 0.23.0.

```
df.to_stata('~/test.dta', version=117, convert_strl=[<the Column the you have the boolean valu>])
```

Comment: this does not preserve the boole type but converts it to string.

Comment: Yeah but after that you can cast it back to bool right??

Comment: OK, not really convenient though. I think I switch to another format

Comment: Yeah try csv it will preserve anything and compatibility is there.